# Pagination using featherjs in node js

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

how to pagination adding in node js using feathers js framework?

i am currently using feather js framework front-end angular back-end nodejs i am facing issue pagination. Any solutions

Answer (score 1):

Feathers.Js have their own pagination option on the service.

If you generate a service by the generator then the pagination is already generated.

Set pagination from config

```js
const options = {
    Model: createModel(app),
    paginate: app.get("paginate"),
};
```

Set pagination manually

```js
const options = {
    Model: createModel(app),
    paginate: {
        "default": 10,
        "max": 50
    },
};
```

for disable pagination

```js
const options = {
    Model: createModel(app),
    paginate: false,
};
```

Comment: But how do you actually use this in a GET request?